# Spring Javaconfig based autowire by name not working

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I am trying to use Javaconfig based Spring configurations. I have two beans of same type and trying to autowire them by Qualifier. But it does not seems to working.

This is my Configuration class

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan("com.test")
    public class BasicConfig {
        @Bean(name = "mysqlSource")
        @Qualifier("mysqlSource")
        public DataSource jdbcTemplateMySql() {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
            dataSource.setUsername(mysqlUser);
            dataSource.setPassword(mysqlPass);
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean(name = "oracleSource")
        @Qualifier("oracleSource")
        public DataSource jdbcSourceOracle() {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@lab-scan.tigeritbd.com:1521/evidb.tigeritbd.com");
            dataSource.setUsername(oracleUser);
            dataSource.setPassword(oraclePass);
            return dataSource;
        }
    }
```

This two are my other classes where I am trying to use autowire them.

```
    
    @Repository
    public class TrackingInfiniDBRepo implements DataPutRepo {
        private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Autowired
        void setJdbcTemplateOracle(@Qualifier("mysqlSource") DataSource dataSource) {
            jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
    }
    

    
    @Repository
    public class OracleDataFetcherRepo implements DataFetcherRepo {
        private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateOracle;
        @Autowired
        void setJdbcTemplateOracle(@Qualifier("oracleSource") DataSource dataSource) {
            jdbcTemplateOracle = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
    }
```

But when I start my application via `ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(BasicConfig.class)` it throws an exception.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: mysqlSource,oracleSource
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
        at com.tigerit.tracking.Application.main(Application.java:21)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: mysqlSource,oracleSource
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: mysqlSource,oracleSource
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:970)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 17 more
```

I am out of idea. I tried to google it but all seems to suggest adding Qualifier. But I have already add that but with no use. Please help. I am using Spring 4(current version).

Comment: Spring Boot expects, due to the absence of a `JdbcTemplate`, that there is a single datasource so that an automatically configured `JdbcTemplate` can be added. However you have 2 datasources. In the `@ EnableAutoConfiguration` add an exclude for `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of your `DataSources` has to be `@Primary` (see [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources)).

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. Did not thought about reading spring boot doc. Was only reading spring configuration, annotations docs.

Comment: The docs don't actually say that `@Primary` is required, but it seems that it is.