# Multiple datasource beans are created while using datasource-proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, datasource

I was trying to implement datasource-proxy with my current application from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/datasource-proxy/wiki/HowToUse)

I configured datasource object as in spring xml, i.e. passing dataSourceReal in dataSourceProxy object.

Listener and filter are properly configured as in docs.

Spring xml file :

```
<bean id="dataSourceReal" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDS" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </bean>


     <bean id="dataSourceProxy" class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyDataSource">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceReal" />
            <property name="listener" ref="listeners" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="listeners" class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.ChainListener">
            <property name="listeners">
                <list>
                    <bean
                        class="com.my.sql.logging.DataSourceQueryLoggingListener" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

xml file for JNDI name for datasource name :

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDS" auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="25" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
username="abc" password="abc"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:myDB"
validationQuery="Select 1 from dual" />
```

I am getting this error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [dataSourceReal, dataSourceProxy]
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you use @Autowired anotation in your code ?

Comment: I have not used @Autowired annotation for this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found solution to this problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116355/spring-javaconfig-based-autowire-by-name-not-working)

Whenever we have more than one datasource configured with our application,

we can specify `@Primary` annotation on our primary bean in java

OR

when using xml, we can specify our primary bean as

```
<bean id="dataSourceProxy" primary="true" class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyDataSource">
```